# Как объявить функцию, если не объявлена

Tags: c++, c, препроцессор

На ОС Linux есть функция *getchar_unlocked()*

Но Шинде такая функция по-умолчанию *undefined*

Я тут подумал, можно ли проверять, объявлена ли функция и если нет - объявить самим

Есть код:

```
#ifdef _WINDOWS
// no getchar_unlocked on Windows so just call getchar
inline int getchar_unlocked() { return getchar(); }
#endif
```

НО! Постоянно следить за тем, чтоб `_Windows` был определен на Шинде и неопределен в Linux мутно, можно ли автоматизировать данный процесс

Comment: Макрос? `#define getchar_unlocked` на windows `getchar` на linux `getchar_unlocked`?

Comment: Что такое "Шинде"?

Comment: Аналогом getchar_unlocked в "Шинде", по видимому, является [_getchar_nolock](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/getchar-nolock-getwchar-nolock?view=vs-2019) из расширений Microsoft CRT, а не getchar. Я бы не рекомендовал создавать функцию, которая на одной ОС является потокобезопасной, а на другой нет, это выглядит как отличный способ наплодить багов.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вообще вы написали бред в вопросе, и непонятно что вы имеете ввиду под автоматизацией процесса, когда препроцессор делает это и так за вас, но не суть.

Определите макрос:

```
#ifdef _WINDOWS
#define getchar_unlocked getchar
#else
#define getchar_unlocked getchar_unlocked
#endif
```

Теперь при развертывании `getchar_unlocked`, он будет превращаться либо в `getchar_unlocked` или в `getchar`.

Comment: На самом деле метка `_WINDOWS` вроде не обязательно должна присутствовать, зависит от хеадеров и компиллера. Стандартные: `_WIN32`,`_WIN64`,`__WIN32__`,`__WIN64__`,`__WINNT`,`__WINNT__`,`WINNT`. И для суб платформ: `__CYGWIN__`, `__MINGW32__`, `__MINGW64__`,`_MSC_VER`.